# Having difficulty with SQL query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am working on a problem where I have to create an SQL query retrieving all employees and the respective sum of invoice totals for the customers they support. Please order the result set in descending order by the total invoice sum.

Here is the schema:

[image: Schema]

Here is the output of the problem:

[image: Output]

Here is my SQL query:

```
select e.EmployeeId,  avg(i.Total) as total 
from employees as e, invoices as i ;
```

Comment: "where I have to create", is this a job task or a school task? Have you been given any guidance on how to do this? Do you know enough SQL to know how to join tables?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Little Knowledge on SQL, it is a school task. I have added the schema and the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join 3 tables and apply `order by`; I *guess* that's OK because model doesn't show entire `invoices` table ("4 more columns", eh?)

```
select e.employee_id,
       sum(i.total) as sum_total
from employees e join customers c on c.supportrepid = e.employee_id
                 join invoices i on i.customerid = c.customerid
group by e.employee_id
order by 2 desc
```